# WPF BubbleSeries, iterate over the bubbles and set the style

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have a BubbleSeries within a Chart. I bind data to the BubbleSeries and set a specific color to the bubbles.

What I want to do is to iterate over all the bubbles and set each bubble's color to specific color depending on the value.

My bubbles, two series:
[image]

The gray bubbles should always be gray, but the blue bubbles should have different colors depending on their SizeValue.

Any clues how to iterate over the bubbles and set their specific color? Possible?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a solution:

I didn't need to iterate over my bubbles, instead I solved the problem with a ValueConverter.

I have a ValueConverter that takes a value and return a color depending on that value.

I bind the response from my ValueConverter to my DataPointStyle:

```
        <Charting:BubbleSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style
                        TargetType="Charting:BubbleDataPoint">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush
                                    Color="{Binding Path=PropertyOnObjectBoundToGraph, Converter={StaticResource colorFormater}}"></SolidColorBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
```